# Convert column type from TinyInt to Int in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database with a lot of tables. Hundreds of columns are of type `TinyInt`. I need to convert them all to `Int`. Is it possible to do that using a stored procedure?

Comment: Firstly, why have you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server? Secondly, why do you want to do this in a stored procedure? This is a one-off event.

Comment: Do you mean you want to alter all of the tinyint columns in the database to int using a stored procedure?

Comment: @DanGuzman, yup exact. I want to alter tinyint columns to make them int using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No easy solution for this.

The simplest approach would be to just have a T-SQL script that you can run that would produce the T-SQL `ALTER TABLE .... ALTER COLUMN ...` scripts as output (on a per database level), which you could then copy & paste in SQL Server Management Studio.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    ColName = c.Name,
    SchemaName = s.Name,
    TableName = t.Name,
    AlterCommand = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.Name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.Name) + 
                   ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' INT' + 
                        CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL;' ELSE ' NOT NULL;' END
FROM
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN
    sys.types ty ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE
    ty.name = 'tinyint'
```

The other option would be to wrap this code into a procedure that would create an `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...` SQL statement as a dynamic SQL statement, and then execute each one, iterating over all `TINYINT` columns. But again: this would be on a per-database level.

*Alternatively*, if you could create those databases from scratch, you could also script out the `CREATE TABLE` script for all tables into a text file, replace `TINYINT` with `INT` in a text editor, and then run those create scripts again against a new database / server.

Comment: I had run a query form `AlterCommand `. But I saw error as `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because column 'dbo' does not exist in table 'once'`...**Here `once` is my table name**

Comment: @marc_s shouldn't that be `+ ' ALTER COLUMN ' + c.name ` - to reference the column name and not the schema name

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish: sorry - I didn't understand your comment initially - yes, the `s.name` is needed with the table - but of course you're right - with the column, I should have used `c.Name` - fixed now

Comment: `QUOTENAME`. Oh yes, people will have tables named `Worker's salaries` and columns named `% Discount` (preferrably when you're not expecting it).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: of course - thanks for the hint - included in my post

Comment: Note that the `ATLER` will fail if the column is referenced by a constraint or index.